# Display resolution settings is wrong

Tags: display, 22.04, display-resolution

I have Ubuntu 22.04 installed on my laptop next to windows and I'm facing a problem with display resolution.
I have my laptop connected to 2 additional monitors, one that is 2560x1440 and one 1920x1080. The first one is working fine but the second one shows in settings 1920x1080 but in reality it is much smaller, all of the icons and windows are huge and it feels like scaling 125 or 150% is enabled. When I reboot and login to Windows, the same monitor has the proper resolution.

Here is a screenshot of what I see on the screen. I did not extend the size of chrome tab or settings window.

[image: screenshot]

How can I change/reset the resolution to REAL 1920x1080? For now it's like 1600x900 renamed to 1920x1080.

Comment: What is "linux resolution settings"?

Comment: I edited it to 'display resolution settings'

Comment: Turn off fractional scaling?

Comment: Nothing changed after turning off the fractional scaling

Comment: I have this problem too. It seems that under some conditions Ubuntu is not able to get the available resolutions of a monitor.

Comment: I am having this issue too on a Zephyrus G15 running 22.04